# Generic Angular component for many cases of use

Tags: angular, design-patterns, primeng

I am setting up a major front-end project to develop with Angular CLI.
This front-end project will rely on a very large amount of Rest API develop with Php Laravel framework. These APIs are 90% identical types, with listing, create, modify, delete (...) entities.

By using a library of components like PrimeNG, I really hope to save some time for the development of my components and the implementation of the project as a whole.
That said, I'm a new Angular developer and I'm not sure I know all the good practices, even after reviewing a number of documentations and starting a prototype.

My goal is to not have an angular component for each Rest API.
For example, all APIs that return a listing should be accessible via a single PrimeNg Generic TurboTable component, right? This component would of course be configurable according to the context of use and the current instance.
For example, I could have multiple instances of this genericComponent to display the list of orders, the list of products, the list of (...).

Instead of create one component per entities, one for products list, one for orders list (...).

What do you think ? Do you have any suggestions or clarifications to help me, please?

Warm regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I would like to share some point. And that is my personal experience.

It is really Good practice to create reusable component. That is highly recommended and you should always try to create reusable component. That will definitely help you to reuse code and remove duplicate code.

Table itself is a very complex things when it will have multiple features like pagination, sorting, filtering, row-selection row expand etc.
Now Suppose you are using a single table component at 3-4 places. And all are having different header, serverside filters, sorting and some doesn't have any feature.

So in this scenario, based on the type of table`Ex: product table or order table` you will have to handle headers, serverside filters and all the above thing dynamically at time of component initialization. In the end you will end using `if else` or `switch` cases for getting table configuration and headers value. And in template you will use `*ngIf` to display the correct values in table based on table type.

Also you have to handle **Events** `@Output` and `@Input`. So it is now becoming more and more complex.

**In shorts If reusing component is becoming very complex then I would say you can go for separate component. Because code maintenance and debugging would also be a challenge.**

If you can make Single component and handle all the required scenario that would be best.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You're right for all points spotted. And all what you said added some doubts in my mind, shared between create one component per API list, or find a correct design pattern for that.
However, I imagined that template should not have any *ngIf but only some header, columns (...) properties to be initialized... To me, in this project all table which works with an hypothetic generic template will have same functionnality rules : sorting, filtering, csv exporting, creating, updating (...). 
For the other cases, they would be created as specific cases.
To meditate :)

Comment: "In shorts If reusing component is becoming very complex then I would say you can go for separate component. Because code maintenance and debugging would also be a challenge." Yes,I have to keep this remark in minds too... But Im afraid to have maybe 400 table components to create in regards of 400 API list...

Comment: @Sébastien Thats why in the last line I mentioned if you can make it possible it would be best. It depends on you how you will make it dynamic. You can also send all the things like api URL, header and other related stuff. Atleast you will not use `ngIf` every time. Only the problem i see is with filters. That part is bit complex. Try to create the filter part as another component and see how it goes.